# Joining two lists that correspond to each other to create a list of class objects

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a single list that contains the username and password of an unspecified amount of users. I am trying to make this list contain class objects of type "User", which is included below:

```
import datetime 
import sys 


class User:

    global_count = 0

    def __init__(self, username, key):
        self.username = username
        self.key = key
        User.global_count += 1

    def showGlobalCount(self):
        print "Number of Keys: %d" % global_count

    def showKeys(self):
        print "username: " + self.username
        print "key: " + self.key + '\n'
```

Simply put, I would like to turn this:

```
usernames = [John, Tim, Scott]
passwords = [password, password1, password2]
```

into this:

```
userInfo = [(John, password), (Tim, password1), (Scott, password2)]
```

The code below is what I have so far. This creates a list that contains the usernames, and a list that contains the passwords. I want to find a way to combine the username list with the corresponding passwords.

```
from Credentials import *

def main():

    with open("Info.txt", "r") as infile:
        data = [line.rstrip().split(",") for line in infile]
        usernames, passwords = zip(*data)

    usernameList = []
    passwordList = []

    for user in usernames:
        usernameList.append(user)

    for key in passwords:
        passwordList.append(key)

    print usernameList,passwordList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help anyone can provide would be much appreciated!!

Comment: You have a text file with comma separated username and password on each line. You extract this to a list of 2 element lists of [username, password]. You zip these together into a tuple of usernames and a tuple of passwords. Then you change these tuples to lists by creating empty lists and iterating over your tuples and appending to the list. What are you trying to do? Why don't you just skip all of the back and forth and just `userList = [User(*line.rstrip().split(',')) for line in infile]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can zip the two lists and then create the objects:

```
users = [User(user, password) for user, password in zip(usernameList, passwordList)]
```

**edit**

although you unzip the data when reading it, and then want to zipped again, I think it's a little waste of time, because data is the list of lists that you need

Comment: How would you print out the list of users then? A simple `print users` statement returns things like:
<Credentials.User instance at 0x10a650758>

Comment: You can define a __str__ method for the class, or don't create the objects: users = [(user, password) for user, password in zip(usernameList, passwordList)]

Comment: @dehone12: You already have a `showKeys` function. Just call it ... `for user in users: user.showKeys()`.